# How can I run an Excel macro from an Outlook macro?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How can I run an Excel macro from an Outlook macro?

Comment: You could take it out of the other file and put it in your Personal Macro Workbook so it's available from any Excel File, [see this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-HA102174076.aspx) for Microsoft documentation.

Comment: In fact, my processing is composed of 2 parties. The first one launches a macro in OUTLOOK, to save an attachement of mail in one specified folder. The second one launches a macro in a excel file. I just want to launch the macro defined in excel just after the first processing, but always in the macro of OUTLOOK

Comment: I think the title of this question is a little misleading. Reading the actual question, it seems like the OP is trying to run a macro in an Excel workbook from a macro in Outlook, not a different Excel File.

Comment: Exactly, sorry for the title that I wrote

Comment: @asp8811 You should make the suggested edit to the title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to add the Microsoft Excel 14.0 Data Objects library. Go to Tools -> References.

You will also need to open the workbook before you can run a macro from it.

This should work:

```
 Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
 Dim ExWbk As Workbook
 Set ExApp = New Excel.Application
 Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder\Folder\File.xls")
 ExApp.Visible = True

 ExWbk.Application.Run "ModuleName.YourMacro"

 ExWbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

If you want to run this macro in the background and not open a visible instance of Excel, then set ExApp.Visible to False.

Comment: Hi, this part throws a problem "Dim ExApp As Excel.Application". It sais that this type is not defined. (I should put the code in a macro in OUTLOOK)

Comment: Did you add the Excel Object library? Until you do, Outlook does not have the necessary references to know what the Excel application is or how to use it. Edit: I tried this code, and it does work if you have the reference. If not, it will throw the same error you're getting. You need to go to Tools -> References. Find Microsoft Excel 14.0 Data Objects Library in the list, and check the box next to it. Click OK, and then try the code again.

Comment: Cool! It works! I mixed MS office 14.0 data objects library and MS Data objects library. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share how I do this. It doesn't apply to OP's needs, but the title may lead others here for more what I'm sharing. This will (optionally filter by sender/subject) save/open/run macro from spreadsheet received in outlook. I then have a macro in excel sometimes which sends notification/response etc, but I don't do this from Outlook (probably could though!).

Create a VBS script which will launch the excel file and run a macro (optionally the macro can be stored in a separate spreadsheet.)

**"runmacro.vbs"**

```
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

ws = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
macro = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
If wscript.arguments.count > 2 Then
 macrowb = WScript.Arguments.Item(2)
End If

LaunchMacro

Sub LaunchMacro() 
  Dim xl
  Dim xlBook  

  Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
  Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(ws, 0, True)
  If wscript.arguments.count > 2 Then
   Set macrowb = xl.Workbooks.Open(macrowb, 0, True)
  End If
  'xl.Application.Visible = True ' Show Excel Window
  xl.Application.run macro
  'xl.DisplayAlerts = False  ' suppress prompts and alert messages while a macro is running
  'xlBook.saved = True ' suppresses the Save Changes prompt when you close a workbook
  'xl.activewindow.close
  xl.Quit

End Sub
```

**Outlook VBA Code (ThisOutlookSession):**

https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/save-open-attachment/

```
Private Declare Function GetShortPathName Lib "kernel32" _
 Alias "GetShortPathNameA" (ByVal lpszLongPath As String, _
 ByVal lpszShortPath As String, ByVal cchBuffer As Long) As Long

 Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objWsShell As Object
    Dim strTempFolder As String
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objAttachment As Attachment
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim Subject As String

    Subject = Item.Subject
    'If Subject Like "*SubTest*" Then

    If Item.Class = olMail Then
       Set objMail = Item
       'Change sender email address
       'If objMail.SenderEmailAddress = "boss@datanumen.com" Then
          Set objWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
          strTempFolder = Environ("Temp") & "\"

          Set objWsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
          Set objAttachments = objMail.Attachments
          If objAttachments.Count > 0 Then
             For Each objAttachment In objAttachments
                 strFileName = objAttachment.DisplayName
                 On Error Resume Next
                 Kill strTempFolder & strFileName
                 On Error GoTo 0

                 'Save the attachment
                 objAttachment.SaveAsFile strTempFolder & strFileName

                 'Open the attachment
                 vbs = (Chr(34) & "\\Server\Excel\" & "\runmacro.vbs " & Chr(34))
                 strFileName = GetShortFileName(strTempFolder & strFileName)
                 macro = "MacroName"
                 xlam = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\Add-In.xlam"
                 On Error Resume Next
                 objWsShell.Run vbs & " " & strFileName & " " & macro & " " & xlam
                 objMail.UnRead = False
Next
          'End If
        End If
    End If
    'End If
End Sub

Function GetShortFileName(ByVal FullPath As String) As String
    Dim lAns As Long
    Dim sAns As String
    Dim iLen As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    If Dir(FullPath) <> "" Then
       sAns = Space(255)
       lAns = GetShortPathName(FullPath, sAns, 255)
       GetShortFileName = Left(sAns, lAns)
    End If
End Function
```